# create new nodes that point at each other

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nodes

```
struct x{
    ...;
    ...;
    struct x * next;
};

struct x create() {
    struct x new = malloc...
    new->... = .;
    new->... = ..;
    new->next = NULL
};
```

When i create a new node of struct x how does it work when using struct x create multiple times. It feels strange for me that you can use it multiple times because It allocate memory to a struct x with the same name new each time? Doesn't each node of a struct require an individual name. Or Does it only matters that each time a new memory allocation is done.

Main problem: I will create first node and then a second node. The first node should then point at the second node and so on. But when I create the first node the second doesn't exists so I can't set first->next = second.

I have looked at linked lists examples but it doesn't improve my thinking at the moment. The code isn't that important as my own understanding and thinking. Please help me think and grasp the concept.

//I tried to follow the sugestions from Degustaf(except the next pointer, basically the same as create a new node) but did the implementation wrong. So I wounder whats wrong with this code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct x{

  int a;
  int b;
  struct x * next;
}

  struct x *create(int a , int b){
    struct x *new  = malloc(sizeof(struct x));
    new->a = a;//namn skitsamma allokering relevant
    new->b = b;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
};


  int main() { 

    struct x *x1 = struct x *create(12,13);


  return 0;

}
```

Comment: `struct x new = malloc...` should be `struct x *new = malloc...`. You would also need to return `*new`. I would honestly however work with just the pointers (return the pointer, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or Does it only matters that each time a new memory allocation is done.

Correct.

But, there are other issues with your code.  In particular, you aren't returning anything from your `create` function.  I see 2 ways to approach this to remedy the problem.  The first is that you can return the struct directly, which means that you don't need the malloc:

```
struct x create()
{
    struct x new;
    new.member1 = .;
    new.member2 = ..;
    new.next = NULL;
    return new;
};
```

Then you can populate it using

```
struct x x1 = create();
struct x x2 = create();
x1.next = &x2;
```

The other possibility is to return a pointer to a struct, in which case this becomes

```
struct x *create()
{
    struct x *new  = malloc...;
    new->member1 = .;
    new->member2 = ..;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
};
```

Then you can populate it using

```
struct x *x1 = create();
x1->next = create();
```

My opinion is that the second option is cleaner as you don't need to worry about individual elements of your linked list going out of scope, although it does require being careful when it comes to freeing memory (needing to traverse the list and free one element at a time.

Comment: If I call struct x *create() should I call it with struct x *create() instead of struct x *x1 = create();? Your sugestions seems great and I tried to create a struct with code you now can see in the same post as my question. I implemnted the code wrong but do not know whats wrong.

Comment: Change the body of your `main` function to `struct x *x1 = *create(12,13)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign the values of the pointers after you've created both.

i.e.,

```
struct x x1 = create();
struct x x2 = create();
x1.next = &x2;
x2.next = &x1;
```

Comment: I don't think you actually want your linked list to contain a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I thing this is what you want but this is a example with intenger numbers in a list also yoy can change the code as you wish.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
struct cell {
   float info;
   struct cell * next;
};
int more (float * k)
{
char ans[4];

printf("Continue Yes/No: ");
scanf("%s",ans);
if (ans[0]=='Y') {
   printf("insert value: ");
   scanf("%f",k);
   return(1);
}
else
    return(0);
}

struct cell * crelist()
{
 struct cell * last = (struct cell *)NULL;
 struct cell * ptr  = (struct cell *)NULL;
 struct cell * list = (struct cell *)NULL;
 float k;

 ptr = (struct cell *)malloc(sizeof(struct cell));
 if (ptr != (struct cell *)NULL) {
    printf("insert value: ");
    scanf("%f",&k);
    ptr->info = k;
    ptr->next = (struct cell *)NULL;
    list = ptr;
    last = ptr;
 }
 else
     return((struct cell *)NULL);
 while (more(&k)) {
       ptr = (struct cell *)malloc(sizeof(struct cell));
       if (ptr != (struct cell *)NULL) {
          ptr->info = k;
          ptr->next = (struct cell *)NULL;
          last->next = ptr;
          last = ptr;
       }
       else
           break;
 }
        return(list);
 }

void printlist(struct cell * list)
{
  struct cell * p;

  p = list;
  while (p != (struct cell *)NULL) {
        printf("->%f\n",(*p).info);
        p=(*p).next;
  }
  return;
}

int main()
{
  struct cell * list;
  int i;

  list = crelist();
  printlist(list);
  scanf("%d",&i);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```